# Printer only printing during system startup

Tags: windows-10, printing, network-printer

I'm having trouble getting a Windows 10 Machine to Print. The Printer that I have used for testing so far, can print from other computers on the same network without any problems.

However the notebook is currently unable to Print to any printer normally. For some reason, when a document is stuck in the print queue, and the notebook is restartet it prints upon booting up.

I've also looked in the EventViewer in "Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\PrintService\Admin" There I get an error message unfortunatly in german, so here my best translation:

"The document 'Print document' owned by user <current user> could not be printed on printer Ricoh Aficio MP C3000 PCL6. Please retry to print the document or restart the printer spooler.
Datatype: NT EMF 1.008. Size of the Spooler file in Bytes: 9437184. Number of printed Bytes: 0. Total page number of the document: 1. Number of printed Pages: 0. Clientcomputer: \\<THIS PC>. Win32-Error code returned by the Print processor: 2250. This network connection does not exist."

Any Ideas on where to look, or explanations on how printing internally in Windows works, so I can use a tool like ProcMon to analyze where it might be going wrong?

Comment: Uninstall the printer driver, restart the host computer, install a new or the same printer driver, restart again and test.

Comment: Did all that. I even confirmed with pnputil -e that the driver war really removed, unfortunatly that didn't help

Comment: Please try the steps in the answer I posted including installing the printer a different way.

Answer (score 1):

**Background:** Print (at the printer) not releasing until restart. Re-installing printer did not work.

**Initial Solution:**

Do an initial repair of Windows 10.

Uninstall the printer driver again.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup  .

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth  .

SFC /SCANNOW  .

Now restart.

Open Control Panel, Devices and Printers and use the Add Printer function to install the printer. Restart again and test.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the Printer Spooler service is not starting on the desktop when you send a print job to the desktop. When you print from your Windows 10 Machine, check the status print spooler service, before restarting the desktop. If it’s started, stop and restart the same follow the steps:

1. Click Start, type services.msc and hit Enter.
2. Look for the Print spooler.
3. Restart the print spooler service.

Also make sure that the service is set to Automatic:
a.     Right click on service and click on Printer spooler service and click on Properties.
b.     Under the startup type, set it to ‘Automatic

[print spooler services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeiyy.png)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunatly that is not the problem. The Print spooler is running, the error message in my question is generated by it in the event log.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was way simpler then I thought. It was our Antivirus solution, blocking network printing by default.

Since we use bitdefender the solution was: https://www.bitdefender.com/support/bitdefender-firewall-blocking-network-printer-2239.html